# As a Substrate dev, what are the most exciting podcasts you're listening to right now?

Tags: community

Working remotely, I use podcasts to energise and get me hyped about the incredible possibilities and potential that we could build with substrate and web3.

What inspiring podcasts are you listening to right now?

Comment: I am eager to find out as well as I've been lacking ideas. Besides, what qualifies  as a substrate dev any way? Does one need to write their original ideas in the form of a pallet to be called a substrate dev? Or does one need to be writing substrate code itself, officially or in their local copy of the repository, I'm curious.

Comment: writing a pallet definitely makes you a substrate dev.

Comment: I love the initiative... But I don't know if this stack exchange should be used for more social and opinion based lost s like this... We likely should use this to open a new meta post to discus

Comment: See this discussion on Meta: [Should we encourage or discourage social & community focused questions?](https://substrate.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118/should-we-encourage-or-discourage-social-community-focused-questions/)

Answer (score 7):

I can recommend the https://relaychain.fm/ podcast from Parity themselves.
It teaches a lot about the ecosystem and involved projects.

Comment: Any specific episode you like most? Why?

Comment: Mostly I really appreciate the "Let's take an hour and calmly talk about why we're doing this and why it's important".
It has been immensely helpful in building my understanding of what is possible in this ecosystem. Going to cowardly say that I don't have any favorites yet, but I really appreciate the mix between the Parachain projects and the Development/Philosophy ones.

Answer (score 2):

- https://www.zeroknowledge.fm/ - One of the best in the web3 industry: it's on ZK Proofs, but much more and a highly technical podcast. Anna Rose is a Parity alumni and as such has guests from the Polkadot ecosystem fairly often.
- https://lexfridman.com/podcast - while the guests are very wide ranging, these discussions are commonly focused on web3, cryptocurrency, blockchain, and various other neg-gen technology innovators talking shop and vision. Illustrious guests as well are in the show list that open up for hours on great topics.

Answer (score 1):

Kraken's parachain auction podcasts are pretty good listens too:
https://podcasts.apple.com/ie/podcast/parachain-auctions/id1567923627

Comment: Big fan. Not super frequent though.